# Изменение вида inline-кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

Привет! Уже долгое время мучаюсь с этим кодом :

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def start(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Russian', 'English','German']])
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choice your prefer language, please.', reply_markup = keyboard)
def name(message):
    if message.text == 'Russian':
        lang = 'ru'
    elif message.text == 'English':
        lang = 'en'
    elif message.text == 'German':
        lang = 'de'
```

Есть 2 проблемы :
1. Когда запускаю функцию выводит ошибку :

```
2017-08-20 18:30:18,684 (__init__.py:291 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: can\'t parse inline keyboard button: Text buttons are unallowed in the inline keyboard"}']"
```

2. Не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы 2 кнопки выводились в одном ряду, а 3 кнопка выводилась снизу.

Буду рад, если у кого-то есть решение этих проблем. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: На данный момент нету возможности изменять разметку `inline`-кнопок. Можно изменять разметку только для `KeyboardButton` - [`ReplyKeyboardMarkup`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup)

Answer (score 2):

1. Нужно использовать `InlineKeyboardButton` вместо `KeyboardButton`. Исключение возникает потому, что требуется еще задать `url` или `callback_data`
2. Использовать метод `InlineKeyboardMarkup.row()` или при инициализации инлайн-клавиатуры указать `row_width=2`